# Showing push notification message as JSON string when app is open

Tags: php, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I have integrated push notification in react native using "react-native-push-notification" library. 
When app is closed push notification message is displaying proper with title and message but when app is open notification message shown as JSON string like {"title":"Notification Title","body":"This is test message"}

**React Native Code**

```
var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");

PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function(token) {
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);
  },

  onNotification: function(notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },
 senderID: "Sender id",

  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true
});
```

**PHP Script**

```
 define('API_ACCESS_KEY',API_ACCESS_KEY);
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token='token';

    $notification = [
            'title' =>'Test App',
            'body' => 'This is test message',
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        echo $result;
```

Comment: try to print the whole message in console for both the state( closed and foreground ), and share the value here

Comment: hi @abhikumar ..for foreground state getting response --> NOTIFICATION: {"finish": [Function finish], "foreground": true, "id": "111485659", "message": "{\"title\":\"Test App\",\"body\":\"This is test message\"}", "moredata": "dd", "title": "Test App", "userInteraction": false}    and for closed state console is not logged . ..

Comment: i have also implemented react native push notifications, the thing is we have to see first for both the cases, in which variable name the date is coming from the firebase, so that we can proceed further. That's why i have told you to show what you are getting. Try to console it on android studio's console.